# What information do we need to draw the graph of the function?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, graphing-functions, maxima-minima

We have the function $$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ f(x)=\frac{x+1}{e^x}$$

I want to draw the graph of the function.

$$$$

I have calculated the following :

The first derivative is $f'(x)=\frac{-x}{e^x}$ and the second derivative is $f''(x)=\frac{x-1}{e^x}$.

We have that at $x=0$ there is a local maximum.

As for the asymptotic behaviour we have that $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0}$ and $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=-\infty}$.

What else do we need to draw the graph ? Do we maybe need also the intersection with the $x$-axis and with the $y$-axis ?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

I have done the following :

[image]

Is that correct? Do we get this from each given information?

How do we see the convexity in each interval ?

Comment: It just depends on how complex the function is and accurate you want to be.  Generally if you identify all critical points (and whether they are minima/maxima/other), x- and y-intercepts, and all asymptotes (horizontal, vertical, oblique) it should be pretty good.

Comment: It all depends on what ways you want the sketch to be accurate, and what you might want to conclude from the sketch. But normally yes, looking for the places the graph intersects either axis is useful information.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28x%2B1%29%2Fe%5Ex

Comment: Could you check the edited part at my question above? Is that correct ? How do we see the convexity in each interval ? @JairTaylor

Comment: Could you check the edited part at my question above? Is that correct ? How do we see the convexity in each interval ? @aschepler

Comment: Could you check the edited part at my question above? Is that correct ? How do we see the convexity in each interval ? @PC1

Comment: That looks great @MaryStar. While it doesn't look quite like Wolfram's plot, as a sketch, it's good. It clearly displays the relevant information. That said, I will point out a slight flaw: the point of inflection looks to be about $0.4$, rather than $1$. However, this is fine for a sketch. I know from experience that trying to get the point of inflection exactly where you want it is an exercise in frustration!

Comment: @MaryStar If you want more detail you can add inflection points to the list as well, and figure out convexity between the inflection points.  From the formula for $f''(x)$  it's clear that it's convex-down for $x< 1$ and convex-up for $x>1$.

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

It truly depends on how accurate you want to be. But a good idea would be to first make points at all the numerical values, for example at $x=1$ you make a point with the height $3/e^2$. You can then do this again but with all the values that are in-between two numerical values,for example at $x=1.5$, you can keep doing this until you have a satisfying amount of points, then you can draw a line between the points!

[Example of drawing points and then drawing lines between the points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpUVb.png)

Comment: What do you mean by numerical values? The point $x=1$ is arbitrarily chosen?

Comment: Could you check the edited part at my question above? Is that correct ? How do we see the convexity in each interval ?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I can se how that may sound confusing. I meant making a point at whole values (1, 2, 3 and so on) along side the x-axis, with the height of y, ($y=(1+x)/e^x$). Please look the picture I've linked at the bottom of my answer

Comment: Thank you!! :-)